# Can you directly remove a 1D arraylist from a 3D arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

To clarify, I’m wondering if you can remove a 1D arraylist directly from a 3D ArrayList without having to first locate the 2d arraylist containing said 1D array.

It’s hard to explain, so here’s an example:

```
ArrayList<String> berries=new ArrayList<String>();
berries.add("blueberry");
berries.add("strawberry");

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fruit=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
fruit.add(berries);

ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> food=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
food.add(fruit);

//Can I do this?
food.remove(berries);

//Or do I have to do something like this?
food.get(food.indexOf(fruit)).remove(berries);

//I want to remove the ArrayList itself, not just its contents
```

I just wanted to simplify the example, so pretend the ArrayLists contain more elements than shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `remove` on the instance of `food`, because it only contains the `fruit` list, and the `equals` method of `ArrayList` will not inspect subsets of the list.

To get at the berries in your collection, you *must* first traverse through `fruit`.

Comment: Thought so. Thanks for the answer. Question: would food.get(food.indexOf(fruit)).remove(berries); work, then?

Answer (score 0):

If you execute this code (I added some more food into your example), you can conclude the answer by yourself:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> berries = new ArrayList<>();
    berries.add("blueberry");
    berries.add("strawberry");

    ArrayList<String> apples = new ArrayList<>();
    apples.add("green apple");
    apples.add("red apple");

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fruit = new ArrayList<>();
    fruit.add(berries);
    fruit.add(apples);

    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> food = new ArrayList<>();
    food.add(fruit);

    ArrayList<String> freshMeat = new ArrayList<>();
    freshMeat.add("pork");

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> meat = new ArrayList<>();
    meat.add(freshMeat);
    food.add(meat);

    System.out.println("food " + food);

    food.get(food.indexOf(fruit)).remove(berries);
    System.out.println("food " + food);

}
```

The output is:

```
food [[[blueberry, strawberry], [green apple, red apple]], [[pork]]]
food [[[green apple, red apple]], [[pork]]]
```

Beside, this kind of programming is not appropriate for OO languages.
My suggestion is to make the `interface` or an `abstract class` of `Food` type, then use the inheritance...